# Message from webpage xmlLib Error / msxml3 & msxml6

Tags: xml, database-connection, msxml, msxml6, msxml3

At work some users are getting an xmlLib Error when trying to run a certain web based database. We used to get it when running Windows XP machines but was able to fix by replacing the later version of msxml3.dll with a newer version containing certain security functions we required. Now with all of the Windows 7 machines the issue has returned but the old fix obviously does not work. At first I thought it may have been because the dllcache folder is no longer called that in Windows 7, which is correct but changing paths to reflect the changes did not fix the issue. I am leaning towards msxml3.dll not being used in Windows 7 and that it must be a newer version, msxml6.dll?? The other reason I want to think this is because awhile back when I original was set to work on this issue, quit because more important things came up, I was reading in the code reference to msxml3.dll but nothing regarding newer versions of this dll. I have also been searching around the net via Google and have not came up with anything close enough to try. Again though I am not very good with XML at all so I may be talking gibberish. Please see below for the error message.

> Message from webpage
>
> xmlLib Error: the updateGram response was not
>   valid xml. Check your document and path. -1072896682 - Invalid at the
>   top level of the document.

To me, even from my limited XML knowledge, the error appears to showing a invalid connection path to the database.

Does anyone think running a validation on the code could be helpful? I did not write the code nor helped with it so I cannot say if it was done or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1072896682 (XML_E_INVALIDATROOTLEVEL, 0xC00CE556) normally means that DTD processing is prohibited while the XML contains one. You can verify this by debugging the code to check if [ProhibitDTD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is set and the XML contains DTD. To fix this, you may either turn it off or remove DTD from XML.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This helps to confirm that the xml will need to be modified/rewrote to adjust for Windows 7.